# Windows (Phone) 8 - Starting a background Metro app with windows startup

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

Let's say I want to create a Metro app, that changes every now and then the lock screen image on a Windows 8 PC.

Using a normal desktop app this would be fairly easy. I would simply place a shortcut to the startup folder.

But shall I do this with a metro app? I know it is not possible to start a metro app at startup, and it would be silly to do so.

**1. What I want is to have a background worker thread started on startup, that changes the lock screen image once every few hours.** The time intervals between changes don't have to be explicit.

I guess this could be done on Windows 8 by putting a shortcut to an exe, which functions as this background worker. **2. Does such a work-around fit in to the Windows Store regulations?**

**3. How about Windows Phone 8?** As far as I know, this work-around is not viable on WP 8 systems since there is no Startup folder.

**4. What is the best way to implement communication between my background thread, and the front-end metro app?** So for example in my app I want the background thread to randomly select an image from a folder and set it as the lock-screen image, while in the front-end metro app the user could manually select an image from that folder, and set it as the lock-screen image. (This question is about architectural design mostly.)

Comment: It clearly is possible for a Windows Store app to have a background task. But I doubt that a store app can change the lock screen image. It would certainly not be able to do so without user consent, and I see no associated capability mentioned in the manifest.

Comment: On the phone this can be done: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968.aspx

Comment: There are a number of tutorials and articles about how to implement Background tasks on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977055.aspx

Comment: @WiredPrairie But if I register a Background task as you suggested, it will not be restarted after a reboot AFAIK. So it is not viable.

Comment: What is "it" that isn't viable? You can't change the lockscreen, so I don't understand what you're asking about. If the Background task APIs don't meet your need, then there aren't any other options that are available to a Windows Store application.

Comment: The lock screen was just an example.. The point is to run something in background that is executed even if the app is not started by the user. So Background tasks have to be started by the application, which has to be started by the user. Thats why I said Background tasks are not viable for my task.

Answer (score 1):

MS published a sample app which changes your Windows 8.1 lock screen based on an RSS feed.  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Personalization-App-sample-9ebfe147

Comment: Sounds great. I will check out as soon as the windows 8.1 update finished..